# ListView not behaving normally after updating proguard

Tags: android, listview, proguard, android-proguard

I just updated proguard-rules.pro and noticed that ListView is not behaving normally, now ListView items are not appearing.

I added these two lines:

```
-keep class com.google.android.libraries.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

I am facing this issue only with ListView, RecyclerView works just perfect.

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit.http.** <methods>;
}
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keepattributes Signature,Annotation,EnclosingMethod,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.google.android.libraries.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Comment: add model class (using in listView ) rule in pro file as well

Comment: you mean like -keep class Users where Users is a model Class @KhizarHayat

Comment: @KhizarHayat tried with this : -keep class model.UsersPojo but still facing same issue

Comment: your rule is not right if it is directory name

Comment: -keep class model.UsersPojo.** { *; }  use this

Comment: Ok let me check... I thought that I don't need to use .** { *; } with model class

Comment: still facing same issue ... @KhizarHayat

Comment: Hmm but my problem was solved using this rule. I can't help you more than this. sorry

Answer (score 0):

add this to progaurd rules if your are using **android.widget.ListView**

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget { *; }
```

Comment: yet not resolved... using import android.widget.ListView;

Comment: what is happening exactly ?. ListView is not shown ?

Comment: are you using a Pojo class for the data set ?

Comment: yes... I am using pojo class for the data set and tried with this : -keep class model.UsersPojo but still facing same issue